# Magento 2 - How to update grand total when shipping method is changed?

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, totals, grand-total

How can I update the grand total value when shipping method is changed to reflect new calculation?

When you change the shipping method here,
[image]

It must reflect the new calculation in TOTAL section.
 [image]

Comment: you mean to say right part of checkout page?

Comment: Yes that is correct, the summary section.

Comment: Either you need to create a custom extension of change in default magento files, and make custom code to do this things.

Comment: Did you got any solution?

Answer (score 3):

I have the solution First of I found its easier to copy all the files into my theme directory.

1. Create the theme directory

   http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html
2. Overwrite Checkout pages

   ```
   app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Checkout/
   ```
3. Copy web folder from default theme to your Magento_Checkout

   ```
   vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/Magento_Checkout/web
   ```
4. Edit `Magento_Checkout/web/template/summary/` (totals & grand-total) remove code below from both files.

   ```
   <!-- ko if: isDisplayed() -->
   <!-- /ko -->
   ```
5. Edit `Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/shipping.js`

   Find selectShippingMethod Function line 215 and add

   ```
   setShippingInformationAction();
   ```

   Should look like this

   ```
   selectShippingMethod: function (shippingMethod) {
       selectShippingMethodAction(shippingMethod);
       checkoutData.setSelectedShippingRate(shippingMethod.carrier_code + '_' + shippingMethod.method_code);
       setShippingInformationAction();
       return true;
   },
   ```
6. Run following commands

   ```
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
   php bin/magento indexer:reindex 
   php bin/magento cache:flush
   ```