# Not update the shipping total and Order Total after change the shipping methods

Tags: magento2.2, totals, magento2.2.3

Steps to reproduce
go to cart xxx.com/checkout/cart/
change the shipping methods

not update the shipping total and Order Total after change the shipping methods

i am usging 2.2.3

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153426/magento-2-how-to-update-grand-total-when-shipping-method-is-changed/186862#186862

Comment: @niceonelee did you find the answer ?If yes please let us know because i am also facing same issue